# What is the meaning of として　here?

Tags: meaning

> 米政府は3日発表された北朝鮮の核問題を話し合う6者協議の合意の後続措置***として***、北朝鮮をテロ支援国のリストから削除する問題を早急に議会と協議すると明らかにした。

Answer (score 4):

This として is like "as" used to mark a function/role. It's the same as として in the following examples:

- 贈り物として時計をあげる
  to give a watch as a gift
- 母は私を子供として扱う。
  My mother treats me as a child.

Thus ～の後続措置として means "as a next measure following ～" or "as a follow-on action after ～".

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness. I understand the basic meaning of として but wasn't sure about the meaning of the sentence. Now with your confirmation I can fully understand the sentence. Thank you again ^^

Comment: @monolazy Never mind, but please always try to add your partial translation attempt or explain why you are stuck. "Just translate this for me" type questions are frowned upon here. I was also unsure if this answer was what you wanted because you appear to be an experienced reader.